# Is there any webdriver version (above 3.0.0) compatible with firefox latest versions?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

Is there any compatible firefox version to webdriver 3.4.0 .
Do you have any working webdriver version (after 3.0.0) against latest firefox version on window 10?
Please let me know your inputs as well as geckdriver version as well.

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 along with latest gecko driver 0.16 & Mozila Firefox 53.0, you need to download the gecko driver and save it. Mention the absolute location of gecko driver in your code as follows:

```
public void sampleMethod() 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://your_url.com");


}
```

Let me know if it solves your query.

Comment: Great news, glad to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, I found that the same combination does not work in another windows system. I am getting error    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V
       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.usingPort(DriverService.java:269)
       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:228)

Answer (score 1):

firefox browser 46.0 version and it will definitely work and I tried it.

Let me know if there is any issue